# Can gold passives be stacked on a minion kill?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I was Gangplank, and killed a minion with my Q on Twisted Treeline with control of at least one altar, and had the Avarice blade, would I receive gold for all of the above bonuses?  Or would some of them cancel each other?

How many gold passives can stack?  Is there a maximum gold limit per minion kill?

*Edit: Deleted the outdated things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I first point out that for the most part, all the prior answers are correct. Yes, all gold passives do stack, however, there's a bit of a catch. As of Patch 3.14 the gold granting items were overhauled. With the exception of Avarice Blade, a character is not allowed to posses more than one "Gold Income" item. The Gold Income items are:

- Jungle Items

  - Spirit of the Spectral Wraith - Conservation
  - Spirit of the Lizard Elder - Conservation
  - Spirit of the Ancient Golem - Conservation
  - Wriggle's Lantern - 40% More gold from jungle monsters
- Support items

  - Relic Shield / Targon's Brace / Face of the Mountain - Spoils of War
  - Ancient Coin / Nomad's Medallion / Talisman of Ascension - Favor
  - Spelltheif's Edge / Frostfang / Frost Queen's Claim - Tribute

Keep in mind the support items do change the passives a little with each upgrade, as well as two of them including a gold per 10 seconds. In theory, the passives from these items would indeed stack, but the game does not allow you to have more than one.

Any other Gold related passives, such as Twisted Fate's passive ability (keep in mind it is no longer a team-wide effect), Draven's passive, and Ashe's Hawkshot `E` passive, will stack with Avarice Blade, and effects of the gold income items.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: Twisted fate ultimate isn't global anymore. It got changed to 1-6 gold for TF himself on lasthits.

Now to your real Question: There is **no** limit to stacking gold. All the passive on lasthit gold bonuses stack and don't cancel eachother. (But I don't recommend focussing on gold builds on GP/TF)

Comment: An avarice blade on gangplank can actually be quite a good item, critical harass with parrlay and statik shivcan be very strong.

Answer (score 0):

1) TF bonus no longer gives global gold ([as Jutschge mentioned in his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/157815/12936))

2) Having the second alter on Twisted Treeline gives you a damage buff, not a gold buff.

Yes, all gold bonuses stack from environment/abilities/items.  You can only receive a single gold bonus from items though.